# Chat messages does not load properly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have tried to create a chat message system but the old messages seems to still remain when the new messages are called.

[image: Error picture here]

Anyone can help? Furthermore, sometimes when a new user is created and he chat with another user.The messages from the other user is not reflected in the new user chat.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            navigationItem.title = "Chat"
            DispatchQueue.global(qos:.userInteractive).async {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPosts()
                    self.loadPostsReceivedMessage()
                }
            }
        }

    //Get Message sent
       func loadPosts() {
            let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let chatsRef = db.collection("chats").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
            chatsRef.whereField("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!).whereField("receiverID", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
                .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }
                    for document in documents {
                        let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                        let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? String
                        let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String
                        let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                        guard let sender = document.data()["sender"] as? String else {return}
                       // let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                        guard let profileUrl = document.data()["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                        let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
        self.chats.append(chat)
        print(self.chats)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        }
        }


        //Get message received
        func loadPostsReceivedMessage() {
           /* let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    let currentUser = dic["username"] as? String
                    let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                } */
                    let chatsRef = db.collection("chats").order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
                    print("thecurrentreceiver"+senderString)
                    print("thecurrentsender"+receiverIDNumber)
            chatsRef.whereField("receiverID", isEqualTo: senderString).whereField("sender", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
                        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                                return
                            }
                            for document in documents {
                                let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                                let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? String
                                let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String
                                let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                                // let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                                guard let profileUrl = document.data()["profileUrl"] as? String else { return}
                                guard let sender = document.data()["sender"] as? String else {return}
                                let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!,profileImageUrl: profileUrl, senderString: sender)
                                print("whatisthemessage"+messageText!)
                                self.chats.append(chat)
                                print(self.chats)
                                self.chats.sort{$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `addSnapshotListener`, which means that your callback gets called every time something relevant in the database changes. And when that happens, you loop over all the documents that match your query and add them to your view. This means that if there are multiple changes, you're adding most messages multiple times.

There are two common solutions:

1. Clear the view every time your callback gets called.
2. Only modify the view for the changes each time your callback gets called.

We'll use #2 below, since it is more efficient. Note that I'm only handling new messages to keep things simple. As you make your app more complete, you will also need to handle other types of changes, e.g. when a user deletes or updates a chat message.

```
let chatsRef = db.collection ("chats").order (by: "timestamp", descending: false)
chatsRef.whereField ("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!)
  .whereField ("receiverID", isEqualTo: receiverIDNumber)
  .addSnapshotListener {
    querySnapshot,
    error in guard let documentChanges = querySnapshot?.documentChanges else {
        print ("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    for documentChange in documentChanges {
      if (documentChange.type == .added) {
        let data = documentChange.document.data ()
        let messageText = data["message"] as? String
        let senderIDNumber = data["senderID"] as? String
        let receiverIDNumber = data["receiverID"] as? String
        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? String
        ...

        let chat = Chat (
            messageTextString : messageText!,
            senderIDNumber : senderIDNumber!,
            receiverIDNumber : receiverIDNumber!,
            timeStampString : timestamp!,
            profileImageUrl : profileUrl,
            senderString : sender
        )
        self.chats.append (chat)
        print (self.chats)
        self.collectionView.reloadData ()
    }
  }
}
```

For some more on this, have a look at [responding to changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: I am still getting the same error despite trying your code.

Comment: When i exit the chat, and re-enters the chat, everything looks fine. It is just that when i hit the send button, some of the messages will get duplicated.When the chat first load up, the old messages all looks fine too.                                                 @IBAction func sendTextMessage(_ sender: Any) {
    chats.removeAll()
    self.sendDataToDatabase(message: messageText.text!)
    messageText.text = nil
    self.loadPosts()
    self.loadPostsReceivedMessage()
    delayCompletionHandler {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }